# how to make data set contain multiple tables?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dataset

I have the problem to add multiple tables in 1 data set, I only able to load 1 table in 1 data set. I could not get the customer table and item table in 1 data set. Where did I did wrong? This is my first time to do with C# program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace DataSET
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            GetCustDetail();
            GetItemDetail();


        }

        public static void GetCustDetail()
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            DataTable cust_Table = new DataTable();
            dataSet.ReadXml("CustDetail.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);





            DataColumn cust_Column = cust_Table.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(Int32));
            cust_Column.AllowDBNull = false;
            cust_Column.Unique = true;



            cust_Table.Columns.Add("CustLName", typeof(String));
            cust_Table.Columns.Add("Purchases", typeof(Double));

            foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
                cust_Table.BeginLoadData();

            dataSet.ReadXml("CustDetail.xml");

            foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
                cust_Table.EndLoadData();

            dataSet.Tables.Add(cust_Table);
            dataSet.AcceptChanges();
        }

        public static void GetItemDetail()
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            DataTable item_Table = new DataTable();
            dataSet.ReadXml("ItemDetail.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);



            DataColumn item_Column = item_Table.Columns.Add("ItemID", typeof(Int32));
            item_Column.AllowDBNull = false;
            item_Column.Unique = true;



            item_Table.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(String));
            item_Table.Columns.Add("Decription", typeof(Double));

            foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
                item_Table.BeginLoadData();

            dataSet.ReadXml("ItemDetail.xml");

            foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
                item_Table.EndLoadData();

            dataSet.Tables.Add(item_Table);
            dataSet.AcceptChanges();
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the datatable on your dataset..

You can add datatables on dataset like this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: yes, i can add two tables in 1 data set, but my data could not load properly into the tables, e.g. I can load 2 tables separately and load them in each table successful, but when I combine into 1 data set which has 2 table, then it can only successful load the 2nd table data, while the 1st table data could not load onto it....is it I need to use "clear"?

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple table your both datatable have same column name and same no of column then use below code :

```
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Tables.Add(Table1);
                ds.Tables.Add(Table2);
                ds.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: if I do not have the same column name and same no of column? yes, i can add two tables in 1 data set, but my data could not load properly into the tables, e.g. I can load 2 tables separately and load them in each table successful, but when I combine into 1 data set which has 2 table, then it can only successful load the 2nd table data, while the 1st table data could not load onto it....is it I need to use "clear"?

Comment: @iop 

**if I do not have the same column name and same no of column?**

Comment: I have edited my code as above, I could not add my data for the 1st table.